# What to do with big not-so-bad- questions

Tags: discussion

This [Multiple accounts stagnant after quitting job.](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/19059/multiple-accounts-stagnant-after-quitting-job) question is what I would consider a big not-so-bad question.

It doesn't really fit the one-Question-one-Answer fully reusable template.

Neither is it so far off topic (or too specific) to make it closable.

Am I too bothered by this?  Are big questions like this actually usable to future visitors?

Comment: I'm at work, so briefly: Who says the template is one-question-one-answer?  Also, the example given only seems big.  It is actually quite manageable.  (I will certainly agree that it isn't neat-and-clean, but it isn't bad.)  Yes, (good) answers to this question should be quite reusable; if only more of us had this "problem."

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this type of question is a problem.   Rather than several small questions, this reads to me like "What do I do?  This is what I've got: 1, 2, 3. etc.".

It is only phrasing that makes it sound like multiple questions.   If they had said the following, I don't think you'd be asking the same question: "I've got 3 accounts with this much and these loans.  What should I do in this situation?"

Comment: I guess my point was (in part) read as a big question, it is quite specific, with not very much re-use potential.  As such, it seems like not a good question...

Answer (score 2):

I think the body question is good, but the question title is poor.  It doesn't seem to reflect a question that somebody might ask, search on and land here to get an answer.

I would change the title "What to do with various retirement accounts after I quit my job?"

or "How to make the most of retirement accounts after leaving my company?"

But I can't think of something that satisfies me enough to make the change.  Any change would be great.

The point of that question is to get people here from Google, then read the body of the question for context, and then see the answers.  Even though the body is specific with regards to dollar amounts, the advice given would cover a large number of people.

So the key is to write up a title that gets clicks.